# url_for dependent on current path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Given a rails app generated by the following commands:

```
rails new pets
rails controller kitties index
```

We change `config/routes.rb` to the following:

```
RoutingIssue::Application.routes.draw do
  match 'pets/:pet_id/kitties', controller: 'kitties', pet_id: /.+/, action: :index 
end
```

Now on the `rails console` we get the following:

```
2.1.1p76 :002 > ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Generator.new({pet_id: 2, controller: 'kitties', action: 'index'}, {controller: 'blubb'}, Rails.application.routes, false).generate
# => ["/pets/2/kitties", {}]
```

So far so good. To explain: The first argument to the Generator is the controller you want to get a url for. The second argument is the controller mapped to the current request path. Meaning that

```
url_for controller: 'kitties', pet_id: 2, action: 'index'
```

When on a path of the 'blubb' controller results in the call shown on the console.

Now to the actual **question**:

When the same call to `url_for` is done when on a request path to a controller living in a namespace* this is what happens:

```
2.1.1p76 :003 > ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Generator.new({pet_id: 2, controller: 'kitties', action: 'index'}, {controller: 'blubb/blobb'}, Rails.application.routes, false).generate
# ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:pet_id=>2, :controller=>"blubb/kitties"}
```

**Why?**

I would expect to get the correct URL to my kitties controller (i.e. 'kitties', not 'blubb/kitties') no matter what the current request path is. And I don't get why that's not the case. I've been stepping through my application with the debugger until I arrived at the code shown above on the console (simplified and made stand-alone).

* Which looks like this in `config/route.rb`:

```
namespace :blubb do
  resource :blobb, only: :index
end
```

Comment: Using `url_for controller: '/kitties'` fixes this problem.

Comment: Also links to controllers whose routes were generated using the `resource` method in `routes.rb` are generated correctly. Only routes using `match` seem to break.

Comment: Another thing: when `:pet_id` is nil the correct, non-relative path is generated as well. Very confusing.